# Find matching XML node using xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have following XML file which has define the figure ID on following XML node

mainProcedure/proceduralStep/para/@internalRefId

```
<mainProcedure>
<proceduralStep id="stp-0001">
<title>             <inlineSignificantData significantParaDataType="psd52">SUBTASK 72-31-00-030-051</inlineSignificantData> Prepare the Turnover Stand for Installation of the LP Compressor (Fan) Module</title>
<proceduralStep id="stp-0002">
<para>Refer to <internalRef internalRefId="fig-0002" internalRefTargetType="figure"/>.</para>
</proceduralStep>
<proceduralStep id="stp-0013">
<title>             <inlineSignificantData significantParaDataType="psd52">SUBTASK 72-31-00-030-052</inlineSignificantData> Install the LP Compressor (Fan) Module to the Turnover Stand</title>
<proceduralStep id="stp-0014">
<para>Refer to <internalRef internalRefId="fig-0003" internalRefTargetType="figure"/>, <internalRef internalRefId="fig-0004" internalRefTargetType="figure"/>, <internalRef internalRefId="fig-0005" internalRefTargetType="figure"/>, <internalRef internalRefId="fig-0006" internalRefTargetType="figure"/> and <internalRef internalRefId="fig-0007" internalRefTargetType="figure"/>.</para>
</proceduralStep>
<figure id="fig-0001">
<title>Sectional View of the LP Compressor (Fan) Module</title>
<graphic infoEntityIdent="ICN-IHIX1-A0-72310000-R-Z5H62-10946-A-001-01"/>
</figure>
<figure id="fig-0002">
<title>Prepare the Turnover Stand for Installation of the LP Compressor (Fan) Module</title>
<graphic infoEntityIdent="ICN-IHIX1-A0-72310000-R-Z5H62-10947-A-001-01"/>
</figure>
</mainProcedure>
```

On the same XML file, the Figure data has defined on following XML node.

```
<figure id="fig-0001">
<title>Sectional View of the LP Compressor (Fan) Module</title>
<graphic infoEntityIdent="ICN-IHIX1-A0-72310000-R-Z5H62-10946-A-001-01"/>
</figure>
```

So now what I would match the mainProcedure/procedural  and find the corresponding figure ID from  node and infoEntityIdent, display this infoEntityIdent as below

so the end result should be like

```
<html>
<Div> title </Div>
<div id = @infoEntityIdent> para </div>
</html>
```

please, can you help me to design the xsl for this?

Answer (score 1):

Define a key `<xsl:key name="figure" match="figure" use="@id"/>`, then, in the context of `xsl:template match="para/internalRef"` you can use e.g. `key('figure', internalRefId)` to find the referenced `figure` and that way you can use of course `key('figure', internalRefId)/graphic/@infoEntityIdent` to select the attribute value you are looking for with e.g. `<div id="{key('figure', internalRefId)/graphic/@infoEntityIdent}">...</div>`.